# Combine two Lists C# does not exist in current context

Tags: c#

In c# I have 2 lists.

First List is like so:

```
respondent.PrescreenerResponses[i].Response[j] = {[12, some response]}
```

Second List is like so:

```
projects.Prescreeners[i].Questions[j] = {Prescreener Questions: Question}
```

What I want to do is create one list probably like:

```
Prescreeners[i].Responses[j]
Prescreeners[i].Questions[j]
```

My code though is somehow wrong:

```
foreach (var screener in respondent.PreScreenerResponses)
{
    var responses = screener;
}

foreach (var screener in project.PreScreeners)
{
    var questions = screener;
}

List<string> prescreenerResponses = new List<string>();
prescreenerResponses.Add(questions);
```

It tells me questions does not exist in the current context. Same goes for responses when I try to use it. I am pretty sure it the wrong data type but not sure what else it would be?

Comment: The problem is not the data type - it is that you declared the variable  inside of a foreach block, but then tried to use it outside of that block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am pretty sure it the wrong data type

No, it's scope. You declare the `var responses` and `var questions` in their respective `foreach` block. As soon as control leaves those blocks, the variables don't exist anymore.

Declare them first:

```
IEnumerable<PrescreenerResponses> responses = new List<PrescreenerResponses>;

foreach (...)
{
    responses.Add(...)
}
```

Anyway you can also call `AddRange()` if you declase `responses` as `List`, so you can skip the loop:

```
responses.AddRange(respondent.PreScreenerResponses);
```

And it's even more advisable to create a DTO:

```
class QuestionAndAnswer
{
    public PreScreener Question { get; set; }

    public PreScreenerResponse Response { get; set; }
}
```

And use a loop with a counter to fill a `List<QuestionAndAnswer>`:

```
var result = new List<QuestionAndAnswer>();

for (int i = 0; i < projects.Prescreeners.Count; i++)
{
    result.Add(new QuestionAndAnswer
    {
        Question = projects.Prescreeners[i],
        Answer   = respondent.PrescreenerResponses[i],
    });
}
```

Comment: This works but what of respondent only has 1 Prescreener (answer) and the project has 2 prescreeners (questions)? The Answer would throw a null.

Comment: Well yes of course, the code calling this function has to line up the question and answer arrays. What if the first two questions aren't answered, then all answers from the third on are assigned to the wrong question. You can fix this in many ways, for example by including a `QuestionID` property in your `Answer` class, but the solution pretty much depends on how you call this code.

Comment: is there no easier way to handle the null?

Comment: No. How is the code supposed to know what elements from one array belong to the ones in the other?

Comment: I quite simply just want to combine the two results into one list. Prescreener Questions and Prescreener Responses but now I am lost how to do this

Comment: how does including a QuestionID handle the problem? Trying to research it

Comment: That's really a bit too much to explain in a comment, and perhaps there are better ways of solving it. I don't know why you have your data in two arrays and not in a relational model if the two array's don't always line up. You must either have equal-length arrays where the answer array contains null when not answered, or use a list of `Response` object, where `Response.QuestionID` points to the `Question` object it belongs to. If unclear, please start a new question here where you show a small example of input, desired output and relevant code that you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```
    List<string> prescreenerResponses = new List<string>();
    foreach (var screener in respondent.PreScreenerResponses)
    {
        var responses = screener;
    }

    foreach (var screener in project.PreScreeners)
    {           
        prescreenerResponses.Add(screener);
    }
```

Comment: This throws the error: The best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments. – allencoded just now

Comment: Yea i did not realize they were different data types. I would say screener is not a string so cannot be added to list of strings

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing variable "questions" which is declared outside the scope,

Try this:

```
 List<string> prescreenerResponses = new List<string>();
foreach (var screener in respondent.PreScreenerResponses)
        {
            var responses = screener;
        }

        foreach (var screener in project.PreScreeners)
        {
            var questions = screener;
            prescreenerResponses.Add(questions);
        }
```

Comment: This throws the error: The best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It´s because 'questions' is declared inside your loop. You could try the code below:

```
    private class QuestionAndResponses 
    {
         public List<Response> Responses {get;set;}
         public List<Question> Questions {get;set;}
    }

    List<QuestionAndResponses> prescreenerResponses = new List<QuestionAndResponses>();
    for (var i = 0; i < project.preScreeners.Count(); i++) 
    {
         prescreenerResponses.Add(new QuestionAndResponses ()
         {
               Responses = new List<Response>(project.preScreenerResponses[i].Response),
               Questions = new List<Question>(project.preScreeners[i].Questions)
         });
    }
```